# Execute if condition using ssh to get exit value

Tags: ssh, sh

I'm trying to execute this command on a remote computer using ssh.

`ssh user@host "if [ $(ls -la /folder | wc -l) -eq 83 ]; then true; else false; fi;"`

How can I make this part `$(ls -la /folder | wc -l)` to be executed on the remote computer instead of locally?

Comment: Use single quotes everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent `$()` from being expanded locally, put it in single quotes:

```
ssh user@host 'if [ $(ls -la /path | wc -l) -eq 83 ]; then true; else false; fi;'
```

But you don't need the if/else, just do:

```
ssh user@host '[ $(ls -la /path | wc -l) -eq 83 ]'
```